# Why is Compartment search not supported on Hapi DSTU2 server now?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, dstu2-fhir

Up to sometimes back i could perform compartment search on HAPI DSTU2 server, but now i am not able to do so. The following is the request format i was using:

```
http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2/Patient/1548313/Condition
```

Also please let me know about other servers which support Compartment search.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe that has ever worked on the HAPI server. HAPI has support for compartments in its server modules, but the test server does not have that part turned on yet.

We are hoping to work on this soon though..